# How to change the Legend titles in core-plot stacked bar chart?

Tags: ios, charts, core-plot, legend

[How to show bar values on CorePlot -Stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406743/how-to-show-bar-values-on-coreplot-stacked-bar-chart)

following to this post , i want to change the Legend title values for my stacked bar chart , by default it takes the "sets" values given in the code. 
I can't change the "sets" value because i used it to match and get values from the web service.

[image]

The above diagram instead of "D", "O","P", i need to give meaning full name.
I tried a code like this given in coloredBarChart,

```
-(NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index

{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bar %lu", (unsigned long)(index + 1)];
}
```

and then it looks like below,it takes the index value for all stacked-bars in the graph.

[image]

How to change the legend title values in core-plot?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `title` property of each plot to change the label displayed in the legend. You can use the `attributedTitle` instead if you want to display styled text within the label.

Comment: Hi eric i tried like it , 

-(NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
        if ([barPlot.identifier isEqual:[sets objectForKey:@"D"]] == YES) {
            barPlot.title=@"A";
        } else if ([barPlot.identifier isEqual:[sets objectForKey:@"O"]] == YES) {
            barPlot.title=@"AA";
        } else if ([barPlot.identifier isEqual:[sets objectForKey:@"P"]] == YES) {
            barPlot.title=@"AAA";
        }
        return barPlot.title;
    }  But it didnt work out, where i can add bar titles?

Comment: I tired like this to inside the method "-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index"

if (plotIndex ==0)
    {
    plot.title=@"A";
    }else if (plotIndex ==1)
    {
    plot.title=@"AA";
    }else if (plotIndex ==2)
    {
    plot.title=@"AAA";
    }
didn't works please let me know how to fix this issue?

Comment: - (double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{.
   
    NSInteger plotIndex = 0;
    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:[sets objectForKey:@"D"]] == YES) {
        plotIndex = 0;
    } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:[sets objectForKey:@"O"]] == YES) {
        plotIndex = 1;
    } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:[sets objectForKey:@"P"]] == YES) {
        plotIndex = 2;
    }if (plotIndex ==0){plot.title=@"A";}else if (plotIndex ==1){plot.title=@"AA";}else if (plotIndex ==2){ plot.title=@"AAA";}
} Displays  "A"  for all 3 legend Values

Comment: Where can i set title for each plot , please give some ref.

Comment: Set the `title` on the plot during the initial setup. Any time before you add the plot to the legend will work.